# Python Syntax Error within GCP App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up a connection to a MySQL database using python in the GCP app engine.
The goal, a simple test, to be able to have it return/print the first row of a database table.

Using my jupyter notebook I can connect using `sqlalchemy` for python and print the first row fine.

So I tried modifying the initial "hello world" tutorial within app engine to do the same. But when I copy the code into the `main.py` file it gives me a single syntax error when I try to use `create_enginge` on line 7.

Anyone have any ideas as to why it is a syntax error in my `main.py` file in app engine but not in jupyter notebooks?

```
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pymysql
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
engine = sa.create_engine('''mysql+pymysql://{username}:
                             {password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}''')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    # Execute the query and fetch all results
    response = conn.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM table_name "
        "LIMIT 1"
    ).fetchall()
    # Print Results
    for row in response:
        print("sub_event_id = ", row[0], )
        print("event_type   = ", row[1])
        print("date_time    = ", row[2])
        print("ip           = ", row[3])
        print("property_id  = ", row[4])
        print("contact_id   = ", row[5])
        print("address_id   = ", row[6], "\n")
engine.dispose()
```

[Screen Shot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUmDl.png)

Comment: Please post details, code, error messages, etc. You've not given us enough information to help you.

Comment: Could you please share what you've tried so far, what tutorials are you following and if you are getting any kind of errors?

Comment: Sorry about that... Just revised the question with code example and exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@app.route is a decorator, it needs a function to decorate and can't be put anywhere, like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # your code here
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Your problem is not really with the code on line 7  but that you're missing a function definition before it.
And I really doubt it works in Jupyter.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I am strictly running the db connection in the jupyter notebook... not the app code. Adding the function definition fixed my syntax error. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Adding a function definition at the beginning of the code, fixed the syntax error.

Discovered that from polku's answer, Thanks again.